# compute_totals with assemble_jac=True takes longer

Tags: openmdao

I made an explicit component for 2D surface interpolation. For now it uses scipy's SmoothBivariateSpline (i would be happy to hear if this sounds off at the first glance). But my question is about computational time of compute_totals with/out assembled_jac. I asked a similar question before [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947177/compute-totals-takes-longer-with-analytical-gradient-vs-complex-step).

Below is the whole code. By commenting line 81 the computational time changes. And assembled_jac=True case is slower. 
Is this normal?

```
model.linear_solver = DirectSolver(assemble_jac=True)
```

**Detailed explanation of the code:** It creates a surface (x,y,z) and fits an interpolator (x,y --> z). Then selects random points within this surface as sources and targets. The intention is to interpolate the "z" values along the source-target points. So first, the x,y in between source-target are created as "grid". These grid points are my inputs to my openmdao component.

```
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent, DirectSolver
from openmdao.api import  ScipyOptimizeDriver
import openmdao.api as om
# function to fit the interpolator
def f(x, y):
    sin, cos = np.sin, np.cos
    return sin(x + y) + sin(2 * x - y) + cos(3 * x + 4 * y)
x, y = np.mgrid[-7.:7.05:0.1, -5.:5.05:0.05]
z=f(x,y)
# interpolator object that can handle derivatives
interp = SmoothBivariateSpline(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel())
# size of the inputs 3D two inputs 
dim1, dim2, NN = 3, 20, 70
# randomly select some points within the surface created with dummy function above
temp=np.random.rand(dim1)-0.5
recx,recy=temp*7,temp*5 # targets
temp=np.random.rand(dim2)-0.5
tx,ty=temp*7,temp*5 # sources
# get the angles inbetween points source-targets 
angs=np.arctan2(tx-recx[:,np.newaxis],ty-recy[:,np.newaxis])
angs[angs<0]=angs[angs<0]+2*np.pi
# calculate the distance source-target
dist=np.sqrt((tx-recx[:,np.newaxis])**2+(ty-recy[:,np.newaxis])**2) # distance
# create the grid to interpolate from the function and assign as inputs
linser=np.linspace(0,dist,NN).swapaxes(0,1).swapaxes(1,2)

input_xx = tx[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]-linser*np.sin(angs[:,:,np.newaxis])
input_yy = ty[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]-linser*np.cos(angs[:,:,np.newaxis])


class Interper(ExplicitComponent):
    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('interp', types=scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.SmoothBivariateSpline)   
    def setup(self):
        self.interp = self.options['interp']

        self.add_input('t_x_lins', val=np.ones([dim1, dim2, NN]))
        self.add_input('t_y_lins', val=np.ones([dim1, dim2, NN]))
        self.add_output('ter', val=np.ones([dim1, dim2, NN]))
        # counters
        self.comp_count, self.partial_count = 0, 0
        # turns on/off the deriveative approximation
        self.approx_on = 0
        if self.approx_on:
            self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')
        else:  
            print('sparse')
            diag=np.arange(dim2*dim1*NN)
            self.declare_partials('ter', 't_x_lins',cols=diag,rows=diag)
            self.declare_partials('ter', 't_y_lins',cols=diag,rows=diag)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        self.comp_count+=1
#        print(self.comp_count)
        outputs['ter']=self.interp.ev(inputs['t_x_lins'],inputs['t_y_lins'])

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        if self.approx_on:
            self.partial_count+=1
            print('pass')   
        else:
            partials['ter','t_x_lins'] =(self.interp.ev(inputs['t_x_lins'],inputs['t_y_lins'],dx=1)).ravel()
            partials['ter','t_y_lins'] =(self.interp.ev(inputs['t_x_lins'],inputs['t_y_lins'],dy=1)).ravel()
#            self.partial_count+=1
#            print('self.partial_count', self.partial_count)

model = Group()
comp = IndepVarComp()

comp.add_output('t_x_lins', input_xx)
comp.add_output('t_y_lins', input_yy)

model.add_subsystem('input', comp, promotes=['*'])
obj =  Interper(interp=interp)
model.add_subsystem('example', obj, promotes=['*'])

model.linear_solver = DirectSolver(assemble_jac=True)

problem = Problem(model=model)
problem.setup(check=True, mode='fwd',force_alloc_complex=True)

problem.final_setup()

st=time.time()
problem.run_model()
print(time.time()-st)

st=time.time()
totals = problem.compute_totals(['ter'], ['t_x_lins','t_y_lins'])
#problem.check_partials(compact_print=True, method='fd')
print(time.time()-st)
print(problem._mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a weird case, since you have a rather large partial derivative Jacobian in a model that has only feed-forward data connections. If you were doing so by hand, you could solve for total derivatives using pure chain rule. In this case, that would result in a matrix-matrix product. Since you've specified your large example comp with a sparse partial derivative Jacobian, that matrix-matrix product could be done pretty efficiently!

The default linear solver for all groups in OpenMDAO is the `LinearRunOnce` solver, which (without going into all the tedious details) effectively does a single iteration of a block-gauss-sidel algorithm that, in the case of a model with only explicit components becomes equivalent to the matrix-matrix product that you would get in the chain rule. [I refer you to [this paper](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/content/computational-architecture-coupling-heterogeneous-numerical-models-and-computing-coupled) if you want all the nitty gritty details!]

So, why is it faster to use the default solver than the DirectSolver? In this case, the answer becomes somewhat more clear when you consider exactly how the DirectSolver works. It takes the assembled partial derivative Jacobian of the whole Group/Component it's attached to computes and LU decomposition of it, and then uses that factorization to solve a linear system that gives derivatives. You only need one factorization no matter how many times you solve that system, so if you have a lot of solves this is usually pretty efficient.

In your problem, the partial derivative Jacobian of the whole model is (12600x12600), though it is fairly sparse. So thats not small, but its not humongous either. You can see this by using the openmdao command line tool:

`openmdao summary test.py`

Computing, even a sparse LU factorization, for that size of a matrix is going to take some time, which we can look at with the [`openmdao iprof`](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.8.0/features/debugging/profiling/inst_profile.html) tool. I'm making one small change to your model to make things a bit easier to profile with OpenMDAO's built in profiler
`model.example.linear_solver = DirectSolver(assemble_jac=True)`.

Here is a [n2 view](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.8.0/features/model_visualization/n2_basics.html) of the modified model: 
 [image: n2 diagram of test model]

Here is the full [`iprof`](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.8.0/features/debugging/profiling/inst_profile.html) call I used: 
`openmdao iprof -t "With AssembledJac on example" -g openmdao_all test.py`

If you do this yourself, you get an interactive viewer that you can look at. But here is an annotated version I took a screenshot of: [image: iprof output]

You can see that the linearize (the computation of the LU factorization itself) isn't free. Then the linear solve using that factorization is a bit more expensive as well. This really is to be expected. Its pretty hard to beat a bare matrix-matrix multiplication especially when its done with sparse matrices.

Now, I assume your real model is somewhat more complex than this. But if, fundamentally, its still just a feed forward chain of components, then for ones this large you'll probably find the basic `LinearRunOnce` is actually faster in general. If you have some small portion of your model that has `ImplicitComponents` in it or some amount of coupling between explicit components, then it might be faster to put that coupling in its own group and add the DirectSolver to just that portion of the hierarchy. This is covered in a bit more detail in [Section 5.3 of the this Journal paper.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00158-019-02211-z)

Now you might well ask, "should I always just use LinearRunOnce then?"... if only it were that simple. There are lots of different model structures, and the fastest linear solver setup varies a lot between them. If you have a ton of smaller components (e.g. 1000 components with scalar outputs on them, instead of on component with a 1000 element vector output), then the looping overhead of the `LinearRunOnce` solver might dominate and the `DirectSolver` might actually be faster. This kind of model-to-model variation is why the flexible solver configuration that OpenMDAO provides is so critical to getting good performance on a wide set of different kinds of problems.

Comment: I am a bit confused because when I implement many other "feed-forward explicit components" I do not see the same issue even though the size is pretty large. please see the answer below for more details

Comment: ok, we're going to look into this performance issue. It might take a few weeks for us to find the time, but its on the OpenMDAO TODO list

Answer (score 0):

Considering the answer above why don't we see the same behavior for this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947177/compute-totals-takes-longer-with-analytical-gradient-vs-complex-step) ? 
It has similar size and a single explicit component but assembled_jac with direct solver decreases the computational time considerably.

Comment: This follow up question was dead on. We did a bit of performance testing and found some bottlenecks that we were able to alleviate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947177/compute-totals-takes-longer-with-analytical-gradient-vs-complex-step for more details